# How can I parse a JSON response in Python? This is totally new and I don't know which modules to use

Tags: python, json

```
import unirest
import json
response = unirest.post("https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/?cat=famous",
  headers={
    "X-Mashape-Key": "uukT9yvCgjmshXoCpkrCUNaZs3O0p1EwwkQjsnnudFw0VyeJVe",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }
)
print response.body
```

will return

```
{u'category': u'Famous', u'quote': u'Facts are the enemy of truth.', u'author': u"Don Quixote 'Man of La Mancha'"}
```

I'm trying to parse this to state

```
Facts are the enemy of truth - Don Quixote
```

but I can't work out how to parse the JSON. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, but does anyone know which arguments or tools to use? Thanks

Comment: seriously just google it

Comment: I've tried, but I can't google something when I don't know what any of the terminology is

Comment: I am certain that "How can I parse a JSON response in Python" which is literally your question, will yield plenty results ready for use

Comment: What you show is already parsed and no longer json. Just do with the response what you want, e.g. `print("{} - {}".format(response.body["quote"], response.body["author"])`

Comment: syntonym - thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

print ('%s - %s') %(response.body['quote'],response.body['author'].split("'")[0])

Comment: Have you actually tested this?

Comment: no, i haven't, i just tested it now and get that answer i have posted is wrong, i will edit the answer to give correct output in just a moment

Comment: i have tested and edited my answer, it works fine now